# Finish siding after deck removal

Tags: deck, woodworking, siding, sealing, masonry

I recently lost my job when I was going to get this repaired but now funds are limited so must do myself. I need some help on what the best course of action would be though if anyone is willing to help.

The deck that was on the front of the house was poorly made and held so much water so I took the deck off. This is what I am left with. The exposed area is in between my living room and garage. I am needing to complete this so everything is uniform and sealed.I dont know how to get more than one pic posted but I have more if needed. I appreciate any help[image: deck removed]

Answer (score 2):

First off, you're going to have to get a structural engineer to examine the remaining "ledger" or major framing member where the deck was attached to the house to see if it's load bearing and supporting the living room floor. We can't tell from here. You've got a lot of water damage/rot to be fixed and some brickwork to be installed. The siding should be replaced and extended down to the garage door header.

In my humble opinion, this is more than just a DIY fix. Not sure what your skill set is but we're talking about a lot of work do be done on ladders or scaffolding.

Comment: My additional concern would be that the joists have been cut back so far that there isn't adequate bearing on the beam/header.

Comment: Im pretty handy. Ive remodeled both my bathrooms myself (completely gutted). I do all thing around my house but know my limits. I feel like i can mortar a few bricks and do siding. I wish i could add pics so you can see more.